# Poco::CryptoOutputStream determine size

Tags: c++, encryption, c++14, aes, poco-libraries

I decrypt file with Poco::CryptoOutputStream. File size after decryption is changed.

This is my code:

```
Poco::Crypto::Cipher::ByteVec iv {hex.begin(), hex.end()};
Poco::Crypto::CipherKey key("aes-128-cbc", _key, iv);
Poco::Crypto::Cipher::Ptr cipher = Poco::Crypto::CipherFactory::defaultFactory().createCipher(key);

Poco::FileInputStream src("./unit-tests/resources/cipher-stream/segment_000.m4s");
Poco::FileOutputStream dst("./unit-tests/resources/cipher-stream/segment_000_dec.m4s");

Poco::Crypto::CryptoOutputStream decryptor(dst, cipher->createDecryptor());
//<-- In that moment I want to know size of the dst file
Poco::StreamCopier::copyStream(src, decryptor);
```

**Problem**

*I want to know size of the decrypted stream before decryption process is started. Can I do it?*

Comment: The cipher aes-128-cbc is a block cipher. The decrypted size is always less or equal to encrypted size (less on max 127 bytes). It can't be determined exactly until the whole data is decrypted.

Comment: Oh... Ok. I see. Thank you